# Python open a new .txt file, save it, and then print the file path to the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm trying to find a way to print out where the below file is saved once my script is run, to the console for the user to see;

```py
from datetime import datetime
import sys

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y--%H.%M.%S")  

fd = open(r'C:\Test-Folder\Test-File'+dt_string+'.txt','w')
old_stdout = sys.stdout   
sys.stdout = fd

print("this is test text")

fd.close()

print("your file has been saved to: ")
```

Any ideas how i'd go about this?

Comment: why not place your filename in a variable then print it afterwards?

Comment: `C:\Test-Folder\Test-File'+dt_string+'.txt'` is already your path where file is saved to.

Comment: Note that files have a ``write`` method, and ``print`` has a ``file`` parameter. There is absolutely no reason to replace ``sys.stdout`` with your file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually giving the path for the file to save it you can directly console the path `"path+filename"`

if you want to do a check whether the file is saved then you can use the python `os module` to check whether file exists and print the path of it.

```
import os
file = open("filename","w+")
// print Absolute path  
if(os.path.exists('filename'):
    print("Your file is saved at:-", os.path.abspath("filename"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just save the filename?

```py
filename = r'C:\Test-Folder\Test-File'+dt_string+'.txt'
fd = open(filename,'w')
[ ... ]
print("Your file has been saved to: " + filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
fd = open(r'C:\Test-Folder\Test-File'+dt_string+'.txt','w')
print(fd.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y--%H.%M.%S")
filename = Path(Path.home(), 'Test-Folder', f'Test-File_{dt_string}.txt')

print(f"your file has been saved to: {filename}")
```

Use pathlib